# Finding a non-decreasing contiguous subarray

Tags: java, arrays, sub-array, contiguous

Consider an array A[1..n] of random length and random positive integer values. We define a subarray of A as a contiguous segment of A. We denote the subarray from position k to position l (both included) as A[k..l]. The subarray A[k..l] is an ascent if A[j] ≤ A[j + 1] for all j where k ≤ j < l. In other words, an ascent is a nondecreasing segment of A.compute the maximal length of an ascent in A. For instance, given an array A =[5; 3; 6; 4; 6; 6; 7; 5], your algorithm should display:
The maximal length of an ascent would be `4`, and A[4..7] = `[4; 6; 6; 7]` is the longest ascent in the array A. The algorithm cannot use any auxiliary storage such as ’extra’ arrays to perform what is needed. I am not sure how to solve this, this is the closest I've gotten to the solution.

```java
class practice {
    public static void ascentLength(int arr[], int size) {
        int length = 0;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            index = i;
            if (arr[0] <= arr[i + 1]) {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
                length++;
            }
            if (arr[0] >= arr[i + 1]) {
                length = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("length: " + length);
    }

    /* Driver program to test above function */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {5, 3, 6, 4, 6, 6, 7, 5};
        int n = arr.length;
        ascentLength(arr, n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Tracing` a code and drawing `figures` for array is a good way to understand what's your program doing.

```
int arr[] = {5, 3, 6, 4, 6, 6, 7, 5};

int maxLength = 0, count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
    if(arr[i + 1] < arr[i]){
        count = 0;
    }else{
        count++;
        if(count > maxLength){
            maxLength = count;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(maxLength + 1);
```

at last `1` is added because we can't `compare` a number to it self.

Comment: what do you mean by `it does not print the array`? do you want to print the sub array of arr which has the longest non-decreasing order? however, the program print `4` for the `arr = {4,6,6,7}` which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes that I notice right off the bat.

Inside the `if` expression, you're always comparing the first element of the array with the next element. It should be a comparison between the current and next element of the array.

The `count` variable is not declared anywhere. What is the purpose of the `count` variable?

In the second `if` block, you're not storing the length in a separate variable before assigning it to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the size of the current ascent and the longest ascent with separation variables.  On a given iteration you are either starting a new ascent or continuing the existing one.  To simplify the iteration we can handle a few special cases up front (i.e. array that is null, empty, or single-element).

```
public int maxAscentLength(int[] arr) {
  if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  // the largest ascent so far
  int maxLength = 0;
  // length of current ascent - init 1 because 1st element is assumed
  int currLength = 1;
  // start iteration from 1 rather than 0 because 1st element is assumed
  for (int index = 1 ; index < arr.length ; index++) {
    if (arr[index-1] <= arr[index]) {
      // continue ascent
      ++currLength;
    } else {
      // end ascent
      maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, currLength);
      currLength = 1;
    }
  }
  return Math.max(maxLength, currLength);
}
```